# Finding at least 2 elements in a set that satisfys an equation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For any integers $n>2$, show that there are at least 2 elements in $U \big(n\big)$  that satisfy $x^{2}=1$

Looking for a **vital** hint to this question.

My intuition tells me that I ought to try for small n values and ascertain that there are in fact at least 2 elements for any small n values I choose.
Since U(n) is by definition the set of positive integers less than n and relatively prime to n, any n values greater than the small n values for which I have checked to yield at least 2 elements that satisfy $x^{2}=1$ must hold for all any n(large) values
The element x=1 will indeed satisfy $x^{2}=1$.

Comment: Um... 1 is the *only* solution to $x^2 = 1$ if x is a positive integer.  So there will always be *exactly* *one* element of U(n) that satisfy x^2 = 1.  The question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well that's what the question in the book is asking for. What do you mean by it isn't making any sense.
If 1 is necessarily a solution for all n, then all that needs to be done is to find another element x such that the requirement is satisfied and we are done.

Comment: What group structure are you giving $U(n)$ when we determine if there are two elements $x,y \in U(n)$ that satisfy $x^2 = y^2 = 1$? If we're working in the group $\mathbb{Z}$, the only element that satisfies $x^2 = 1$ is 1.

Comment: "then all that needs to be done is to find another element x such that the requirement is satisfied and we are done"  That's my point!  There is NO other element x such that $x^2 = 1$!!!!

Comment: @fleablood 
I take it this is a gibberish question? Suppose n=10 then the element x=9 is in the set. Suppose the operation is multiplicative modulo n.
Will $9^{2}mod(1)$ not equal 1?

Comment: ...unless you aren't in the group Z.  But then what group are you in?  Different groups will have different solutions, including it simply not being true.

Comment: I think there is more to the problem than you are stating.  I was assuming you were in Z but cemulate points out I may have been wrong.

Comment: @fleablood the definition given for u(n) is defined by the book to be the set of positive integers less than n where (n is a positive integer) and relatively prime to n. That is what I am to work with.

Comment: Okay, so the group operation is multiplication mod $n$. Then actually $U(n) = (\mathbb{Z}_n)^\times$ as a group. Got it.

Comment: @fleablood I have not. Chapter 2 question 12 of Contemporary abstract algebra by joseph gallian, fifth edition.

Comment: If the question is $x^2 = 1 mod n$ that's a different issue altogether.

Comment: @fleablood That mod n was not stated in the question. I assume it was mod n based on the use of an example involving mod n.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how did you arrive at -1 aka n-1?

Comment: Namely, $1$ and $-1$ are the two elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ under usual multiplication that square to give the identity. So, what are the analogues of $1$ and $-1$ in the finite group $U(n)$?

Comment: Then you are probably right.  If so, then it suddenly makes a lot more sense.  And it's true by Andre comment.  $(n - 1)^2 = 1 mod n$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I didn't know what the definition U(n) was.

Comment: @cemulate I do not know.

Comment: If U(n) consists of positive integers, why is -1 a candidate?

Comment: For each $n$, temporarily consider the additive group modulo $n$, that is $\mathbb{Z}_n$. By "$-1$", we merely mean the inverse of the element $1$. In $\mathbb{Z}_5$, we have $-1 = 4$, because $1 + 4 = 0$ (and in general, $-1 = n-1$). Now, try out squaring this additive $-1$ in the multiplicative group $U(n)$ (first verify that it's always in there), and show that it works.

Comment: @cemulate
$[+(-1)]^{2}mod(5)=1mod(5)$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Having tried out a couple of n>2 integers, (n-1)^{2} indeed yield 1mod(n). But I am not fully understanding why n-1 works-I've seen in work on paper.
And I am not seeing why (n-1)^{2} divided by n yields 1 analytically(if that is the word)

Comment: @AndréNicolas
The operation in the question is multiplication mod n. So for any element k in the set U(n), the inverse should be kxmod(n)=1 for some element x in U(n). But you have dished out n-k instead which represents the inverse of an element k in Z^_{n} under addition mod (n).

Comment: @AndréNicolas I now understand your explanation of why (n^{2}-1) yields the remainder r.

Comment: About your previous comment, it is $(n-1)^2$.

Comment: The string of comments is very very long. The system frowns on that. I will begin to delete my comments. This will leave room to answer any further question you may have!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can I request an answer with a detailed explanation instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\ge 2$.  The group $U(n)$ of units modulo $n$ can be thought of as having as elemwnts the positive integers less than $n$. The group operation is multiplication modulo $n$. So the product $ab$ of two elements $a$ and $b$ of $U(n)$ is the remainder when the ordinary product is divided by $n$.

Now we turn to the solving the equation $x^2=1$ in $U(n)$.  There is the obvious solution $1$, since the remainder when the ordinary product $(1)(1)$ is divided by $n$ is $1$. Or, to use "mod" language, we have $1^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

For all $n\ge 2$, $n-1$ is a solution of $x^2=1$. To show this, we show that the remainder when the ordinary product $(n-1)^2$ is divided by $n$ is $1$. Note that $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1=(n-2)(n)+1$. So $(n-1)^2$ is $1$ more than a multiple of $n$. In "mod" language we have $(n-1)^2\equiv \pmod{n}$.

If $n\gt 2$, then $n-1\ne 1$, so we have exhibited two different solution of $x^2=1$ in $U(n)$. For completeness we should perhaps explicitly verify that $n-1$ is an element of $U(n)$.

**Remark:** It turns out that if $n$ is a prime $\gt 2$, or a power of an odd prime, then there are *exactly* two solutions of $x^2=1$ in $U(n)$.

But if $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct odd primes, then the equation $x^2=1$ has $2^k$ solutions in $U(n)$. Or, as I would prefer to put it, the congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ has $2^k$ solutions.  As a small illustration, it is not hard to check that $x^2=1$ has the solutions $1$, $4$, $11$, and $14$ in $U(15)$.

Comment: You are welcome.